# An Edit/Refresh button

Tags: trigger, javascript, custom-button

We have custom code on an opportunity that works off an opportunity update.
Sometimes we do an Edit, no change, Save cycle to make the trigger fire again.
These seems like something someone must have done before (or something like it) but I can't find where.

So, can someone assist me in crafting this kind of refresh button?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to actually contain a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Classic, you can just create a button for this. This is found in Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Buttons, Links, and Actions. The following would be the code for a new button that uses the On Click behavior.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
var result = sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Alternatively, in that same screen, you can create a Quick Action that will appear in the Chatter Feed.

In either case, you'll need to add the button, link, or action to your page layouts afterwards in Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Page Layouts.

Comment: I am seeing an error: Error: Unknown function INCLUDESCRIPT. Check spelling.

Comment: now i am getting a box saying error with the onclick javascript - sforce not defined

Comment: awesome, thanks!